# PhP Exception message shown despite been caught by the exception handler

Tags: php, mysql, exception, handler

I have set an exception handler in my PhP program using set_exception_handler() and it actually works fine. In the sense, it does catch exceptions not otherwise handled by me, and as provided in the handler, logs the exception details. So, why am I complaining? Problem is that in addition to logging the correct details with file name and line number in the exception handler, it also displays the following message in the browser:

```
     Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

My belief is that perhaps this specific exception message is coming from stdout stream while the exceptions been caught by the handler are from the stderr stream. The other possibility is that the above message is emitted by the error handler module and not the exception handler module of PhP. In any event, I would like all exception messages to go to one handler.  I also have a error handler set as follows:

```
    set_error_handler('SS_error_handler', E_ALL);
```

How are such situations handled? Is the Fatal error message coming from PhP's error message reporting module? If so, is there an overlap between the exception handler and the error handler in the sense that they both get triggered on certain errors/exceptions?    If relevant, I would like to add that this specific exception is thrown be a MySQL PDO statement.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

add @ character at the beginning of line that causes errors, that will silence it.

also you can ini_set('display_errors', 0), that will silence everyone :)

but usual people just `try{} catch ( e) { trigger_error(e, E_USER_ERROR);}`

Comment: Worst suggestion ever!

Comment: wait, I have more suggestions, just googling ))

Comment: Now it is even worse... Never suppress errors, always log and analyse them!

Comment: Im just sharing common knowledge how to "get rid" of messages, I usually just log them into files

Comment: I am catching the exception and it is caught and handled and logged. Where is the error message coming from is my question. My reading tells me that PhP has two independent modules, the old error reporting and error handling and the new exception handling. Is there some form of overlap there? Does some condition trigger both?

Answer (score 0):

Please reference the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

> The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined
>   function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING,
>   E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the
>   file where set_error_handler() is called.

Hence, you cannot use `set_error_handler` to catch exceptions, you should use proper `try { } catch { }` blocks.

Comment: Please read my questions carefully. The very first line says that I am using an exception handler. If you do not catch an expression expressly, the exception handler should catch it and it does. The question is what is the source of the error message even after the exception is handled? Is it from the exception handling module of PhP or error handling module or is there some other explanation.

Comment: See if these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485371/baffled-php-fatal-error-exception-thrown-without-a-stack-frame-in-unknown-on-l and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14103727/preventing-exceptions-without-stack-frames-with-error-exception-handler-and-shut